# jamovi compute new variable total as sumif cols have text?

Tags: r, sumifs

working in jamovi. I have 10 cols col1 through col10 that either have text or are blank. I want to compute a new variable total_col that simply counts how many cols contain text. Is this a sumif? what would it look like in the jamovi compute panel?

Comment: Sorry, it is not very clear to me: do you want that count row-wise? or do you just want a single cell with a single value that will range from 0 to 10 max?

Comment: I want a single cell with a single value that will range from 0 to 10 max.

Answer (score 1):

The Jamovi module [Rj](https://blog.jamovi.org/2018/07/30/rj.html) allows you to execute R code. The following code will return the number of columns with a *class* that can contain text (*character* and *factor*):

```
sum(sapply(iris, ## replace "iris" with the name of your data set
           function(VAR) class(VAR) %in% c("character", "factor")))
```

Note that in R the class is fixed per column of a dataframe, so the number of cells which *can* contain text will be the same for all rows. If you want to have these identical entries in a separate column though, this should* do:

```
iris$cellcount_text <- sum(sapply(iris, ## replace "iris" as above
           function(VAR) class(VAR) %in% c("character", "factor")))
```

* Not tested, only found that there's a Jamovi module for using R code and supplied the R code (hoping that you can address the underlying data with the name you saved them under).